# Deserializing nested polymorphic fields

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Is it possible to deserialize the following JSON

```
{
  "operation": "create", // type discriminator
  "value": "some text",
  "source": {
    "name": "source name",
    "kind": "db" // type discriminator
  }
}
```

to the following set of classes

```
sealed trait Source

case class DbSource(name: String) extends Source

sealed trait Operation

case class CreateOperation(value: String, source: Source) extends Operation
```

using Json4s without resorting to custom deserializers?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 0):

The Json library Circe offers exactly what you are looking for: [The relevant page](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html)

```
implicit val sourceConfig: Configuration =
  Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("operation")
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know about json4s, you can do it with jackson though:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: That's what I'm using now, but setting up polymorphic deserialization with custom type discriminator fields is quite ugly.

Comment: @synapse 

you mean the annotation 
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
that seems acceptable to me, personally

because you don't have to use the subtypes annotation below, you can register these subtypes on the objectmapper i think, so it's more extensible.
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = Car.class, name = "car"), 
  @Type(value = Truck.class, name = "truck") 
})

is that what you mean by ugly?

Comment: JSON objects have custom named discriminator fields and custom values, so I had to create `TypeIdResolver` (in fact, three of them). Anyway I've solved the problem by switching to `scala-jsoniter` which is faster and has an elegant way to deserialize ADTs.

Answer (score 0):

Use typeHint field
https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-polymorphic-lists
you can change also this discriminator field name ie:

```
implicit val customFormats: Formats =
      new DefaultFormats {
        override val typeHintFieldName   = "className"
```

this example is using field className for all type of traits->case classes.